# How do I hide the menu when I click outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

*There is a website, there is a mobile version. The mobile version has a drop-down menu. This menu works fine, but it doesn't close when clicked outside the block.
I've been looking for a solution on the Internet for a really long time, but nothing came up( I'll be very grateful for the help!*

HTML

```
<header class="header" id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header__inner" id="header">
            <div class="header__logo">
                <img src="Images/ActiveBox_logo.png" alt="Logo" class="img__logo">
            </div>

            <nav class="nav" id="nav">
                <a href="#" class="nav__link" data-scroll="#features">Features</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav__link" data-scroll="#works">Works</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav__link" data-scroll="#team">Our Team</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav__link" data-scroll="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav__link" data-scroll="#download">Download</a>
            </nav>

            <button class="burger" type="button" id="navToggle">
                <span class="burger__item">Menu</span>
            </button>

        </div> <!-- header__inner -->
    </div>
</header>
```

JS

```
 let header = $("#header");
let intro = $("#intro");
let introH = intro.innerHeight();
let scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
let nav = $("#nav");
let navToggle = $("#navToggle");

checkScroll(scrollPos, introH);

$(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
    introH = intro.innerHeight();
    scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    checkScroll(scrollPos, introH);
});

function checkScroll(scrollPos, introH) {
    if( scrollPos > introH ) {
        header.addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        header.removeClass("fixed");
    }
}



/* Smooth scroll */
$("[data-scroll]").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let elementId = $(this).data('scroll');
    let elementOffset = $(elementId).offset().top;

    nav.removeClass("show");


    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: elementOffset - 70
    }, 700);
});



// Nav Toggle

navToggle.on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    nav.toggleClass("show");
});
```

Comment: You could make an invisible overlay underneat the menu, but on top of the rest of the site - and close the menu and the overlay on any click on that overlay.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```js
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest("#box").length === 0) {
    $("#box").hide();
    console.log('clicked outside the box');
  }
  else {
    console.log('clicked on the box');
  }
});
```

```css
#box{
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  padding:5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='box'>
 click me, then click outside
</div>
```

Comment: much better than my comment suggestion

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work in this case